# Golang &(*(&v)) semantic

Tags: pointers, go, dereference, address-operator

I faced an issue today and was able to find it and fix it quickly but do not fully understand why golang semantic is like that.

I'm using Go 1.10.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T struct {
    V int
}

var testT = T{}

func main() {
    t := &(*(&testT))
    t.V = 4
    fmt.Println(t, testT) // test.V == t.V -> t == &testT

    t1 := &testT
    t2 := *t1
    t3 := &t2
    t3.V = 5
    fmt.Println(t3, testT) // t3.V == 4 and test.T == 4 -> t3 != &testT
}
```

#### Output

```
&{4} {4}
&{5} {4}
```

I was expecting not to be equals to &testT so have the same semantics as with t3, but instead I see that &(*(&)) sequence do not have the same semantic if I store intermediary results in variables

#### My question

What is the reason for that behaviour?

Comment: Is this a github issue template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do this:

```
t1 := &testT
t2 := *t1
t3 := &t2
t3.V = 5
```

You take the address of `testT`, store it in `t1`. Then in the next line **a *new*, *distinct* variable `t2` is created which will have a different memory space and address than that of `t1` or `testT`**. Then `t3` will store the address of this new, distinct variable, which is independent of `t1` or `testT`.

When you do this:

```
t := &(*(&testT))
```

You take the address of `testT`, then you dereference the pointer (you get `testT` "back"), then you again take the address of this value which will be the address of `testT`, **there is no new variable created**. So `t` will point to `testT`.

This is normal and logical, nothing surprising is in it. Relevant section from the spec: [Address operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)

> For an operand `x` of pointer type `*T`, the pointer indirection `*x` denotes the [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` pointed to by `x`.

So `&testT` is the address of the variable `testT`, and `*(&testT)` will give you back the `testT` variable. Taking its address again will be identical to `&testT`.

What may hint against this is taking the address of a composite literal. [Spec: Composite literals:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> [Taking the address](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) of a composite literal generates a pointer to a unique [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) initialized with the literal's value.

When you take the address of a composite literal (e.g. `&image.Point{}`), that does create a new, anonymous variable under the hood, and the address of that anonymous variable will be the result of the expression. But taking the address of a variable does not create a new variable.